# Draggable and droppable position

Tags: jquery, positioning, draggable, droppable

Please for help on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interpunkfur/2sum0mhr/)

The problem is when you drop element it does not position well. 
I know the problem is because of left: 12px; in css but cant figure out how to solve.

```
$('.b').droppable({
        drop:function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
        }
});
$('.b').selectable();

$('.c').draggable({
    helper:"clone",
    revert: 'invalid',
    opacity: 0.5,
    grid: [30,36],
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by it does not position well? are you trying to get the red background to fill the underlying rectangle? What are you wanting to happen?

Comment: yep! When you drop element it doesn't position where is showing while dragging

Comment: Hey jsFiddle is awesome, but you can now use "*stack snippets*" instead -- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: oh cool! sorry, i will do it in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this).prev())` instead

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c80y7qrh/)

Answer (score 1):

in css

```
 .b { background: #BBFFBB;
    width: 24px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid; 
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.c { background: #D00000 ;
    position: relative;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.a{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2sum0mhr/3/)

Comment: What do you need the left for? that will not drop where it shows it with that. It will always move it to the right.

Comment: @gmaniac I will asking about that :) So What do you need the left for ? :)

Comment: Because i need it :). it must be positioned little to right

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef sorry I was pointing the question at @int yours and mine are the same I don't understand the need for the `left`

Comment: Ok @int just add  margin: 0px -12px; in your .c class

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmaniac/2sum0mhr/4/)

```
.b { background: #BBFFBB;
    width: 24px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid; 
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.c { background: #D00000 ;
    position: relative;
    width:25px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.a{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

I removed the `left` and `margin`s then changed some of the `width`s  I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: as i wrote I know the problem is because of left but I don't wont it fills div. it must be positioned little to left that is to right

Comment: @int do you have any examples of what you are talking about?